# React Native Image not loading- The operation couldn’t be completed. (NSURLErrorDomain error -1005.)

Tags: ios, react-native

I am trying to load a remote image from a `https` connection but it fails with the following error:

`The operation couldn’t be completed. (NSURLErrorDomain error -1005.)`

```
<Image
  source={{ uri: 'https://movact.de/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/matthias_bannert-e1502644047369-150x150.jpg' }}
  style={styles.speakerImage}
  onError={error => console.log('ERROR', error.nativeEvent)}
/>
```

I tried several other images and they all fail with the same error, any idea what the error means?

React Native `0.49.3`

Answer (score 0):

Works fine/no errors with the following code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Image } from 'react-native';

export default class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <View style={{flex:1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center'}}>
                <Image
                    source={{ uri: 'https://movact.de/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/matthias_bannert-e1502644047369-150x150.jpg' }}
                    style={{height: 50, width:50}}
                    onError={error => console.log('ERROR', error.nativeEvent)}
                />
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

Are you specifying a width and height in your speakerImage style object? Remote images/urls require size attributes.